How to fix touch being grabbed by scrollview and give it to textinput
I made textinput inside scrollview and i want to disable scrolling by mouse buttons (except scrollwheel) because it makes harder to select text
I tried changing on_touch_down function inside scrollview but then i couldnt select anything so i tried to give touch mannualy to all scrollview children , also didnt help
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class CustomScrollView(ScrollView):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.button == 'scrollup' or touch.button == 'scrolldown':
            return super(CustomScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        else:
            for child in self.walk(restrict=True):
                if child.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                    touch.push()
                    touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_widget)
                    if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
                        touch.pop()
                        return True
                    touch.pop()
                    # child.on_touch_down(touch)
            return False


class main(App):
    def build(self):

        scroll_view = CustomScrollView(do_scroll_x=False)


        text_input = TextInput(text="text "*5000, multiline=True,readonly=True, size_hint = (None, None), size = (400,2000), cursor=(0, 0))



        scroll_view.add_widget(text_input)

        return scroll_view

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().run()




Have you tried using a standard ScrollView with scroll_type=['bars']? This eliminates scrolling with mouse touch. See the documentation.

By the way, The TextInput has a simple scrolling mechanism built in, so you may not need to put it into a ScrollView.

@JohnAnderson scroll_type=['bars'] is what i needed, thanks!
